# Displaying Locations countrywise from twitter api Yahoo WOEID

Tags: php, arrays, json, twitter-oauth

Below is sample markup and json, what i'm trying to achieve is use  tag to list all the locations available in json countrywise. I can easily list all the locations but having hard time figuring out a way to list them countrywise.

```
<select>
      <optgroup value="23424977" label="United States">
        <option value="2352824">Albuquerque</option>
        <option value="2357024">Atlanta</option>
        <option >...all locations under united states...</option>

      </optgroup>
      <optgroup value="23424900" label="Mexico">
        <option value="110978">Acapulco</option>
        <option value="115958">Chihuahua</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
```

/*#################BELOW IS A SAMPLE JSON########################*/

```
    Array(
/**********COUTNRY United States*************/

    [335] => Array
        (
            [name] => Albuquerque
            [placeType] => Array
                (
                    [code] => 7
                    [name] => Town
                )

            [url] => http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/2352824
            [parentid] => 23424977
            [country] => United States
            [woeid] => 2352824
            [countryCode] => US
        )

    [336] => Array
        (
            [name] => Atlanta
            [placeType] => Array
                (
                    [code] => 7
                    [name] => Town
                )

            [url] => http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/2357024
            [parentid] => 23424977
            [country] => United States
            [woeid] => 2357024
            [countryCode] => US
        )

    [337] => Array
        (
            [name] => Austin
            [placeType] => Array
                (
                    [code] => 7
                    [name] => Town
                )

            [url] => http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/2357536
            [parentid] => 23424977
            [country] => United States
            [woeid] => 2357536
            [countryCode] => US
        )

    [338] => Array
        (
            [name] => Baltimore
            [placeType] => Array
                (
                    [code] => 7
                    [name] => Town
                )

            [url] => http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/2358820
            [parentid] => 23424977
            [country] => United States
            [woeid] => 2358820
            [countryCode] => US
        )

     [460] => Array
        (
            [name] => United States
            [placeType] => Array
                (
                    [code] => 12
                    [name] => Country
                )

            [url] => http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/23424977
            [parentid] => 1
            [country] => United States
            [woeid] => 23424977
            [countryCode] => US
        )


/**********COUTNRY MEXICO*************/
   [435] => Array
        (
            [name] => Mexico
            [placeType] => Array
                (
                    [code] => 12
                    [name] => Country
                )

            [url] => http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/23424900
            [parentid] => 1
            [country] => Mexico
            [woeid] => 23424900
            [countryCode] => MX
        )
    [37] => Array
        (
            [name] => Acapulco
            [placeType] => Array
                (
                    [code] => 7
                    [name] => Town
                )

            [url] => http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/110978
            [parentid] => 23424900
            [country] => Mexico
            [woeid] => 110978
            [countryCode] => MX
        )
    [39] => Array
        (
            [name] => Chihuahua
            [placeType] => Array
                (
                    [code] => 7
                    [name] => Town
                )

            [url] => http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/115958
            [parentid] => 23424900
            [country] => Mexico
            [woeid] => 115958
            [countryCode] => MX
        )
    [40] => Array
        (
            [name] => Mexico City
            [placeType] => Array
                (
                    [code] => 7
                    [name] => Town
                )

            [url] => http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/116545
            [parentid] => 23424900
            [country] => Mexico
            [woeid] => 116545
            [countryCode] => MX
        )
    )
```

I'm using following code that generates a dropdown menu which lists all the locations but what I'm looking for is to make it more organised so that all the locations that belongs to same country should fall under it

```
   <?php

require_once("twitteroauth.php"); //Path to twitteroauth library

$consumerkey = "*******SECRET************";
$consumersecret = "*******SECRET************";
$accesstoken = "*******SECRET************";
$accesstokensecret = "*******SECRET************";

function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
}


$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/available.json?id=1");


$jdcode = json_encode($tweets);
$loc_namearray = (json_decode($jdcode, true));

$loc_name = array();
$loc_id = array();
foreach ($loc_namearray as $value) {

    array_push($loc_name, $value['name']);
    array_push($loc_id, $value['woeid']);
}
$locations = array_combine($loc_name, $loc_id);

?>


    <select class="locations" id="location" name="location">
        <option>Select Location</option>
        <?php 
         foreach ($locations as $value => $key) { 
         ?>

         <option value="<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option>
            <?php
         }
         ?>
        ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Please provide the code you've tried so far that doesn't work.

Comment: I've added the code I'm using.. Actually the code works and populates the dropdown list all  all the locations but what I'm looking for is to make it more organised so that all the locations that belongs to same country should fall under it like sample html markup in question